# Using MediaPlayer with a Timer

Tags: audio, timer, media-player, ringtone

I currently have a timer that I want to play a sound file when the timer ends. However it's only playing a fraction of audio file I have stored. I have nothing in the code that tells the file to stop playing, so I don't know why this is happening.

I start out with this:

```
public class DrinkinzActivity extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
Timer myTimer;
public MediaPlayer mMediaPlayer;
```

Then in the onCreate method I have this:

```
    mMediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
    mMediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(getBaseContext(), R.raw.soundfile);
```

Then when the timer runs out, I have this:

```
mMediaPlayer.start();
```

I haven't even gotten to the part where the user can pick which sound file to play, or use a ringtone instead. Is there something I'm missing?

Answer (score 1):

Apparently I answered my own question. The audio file I was using was in wma format, and android (being Linux) didn't really like that. I reformatted it to mp3 and it works fine as of right now. It had nothing to do with the timer.